# Moderator is allowing name calling without intervention

Tags: discussion

In this response, although flagged, moderator is condoning respondent calling me stupid. [Are most US mass shooters Democrats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40758/are-most-us-mass-shooters-democrats/40761?noredirect=1#comment229588_40761)

This is how moderator staff gets painted as partisan, because they are

Comment: You need a little more patience... If I could practice omnipresence, I wouldn't be here. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: While I have you, you need to pump the brakes. You've been a ghost since Feb, then you generate 2 "rude" flags in under a day. Not a good look.

Answer (score 13):

- Comment posted: 2020-10-16 19:46:22Z
- Flag raised: 2020-10-16 19:47:34Z
- Meta-Question posted: 2020-10-17 03:54:53Z
- Comment deleted: 2020-10-17 05:39:49Z

Ten hours is a perfectly acceptable response time, especially as this was a non-trivial case.

It is **not** an indicator that the comment was condoned.

> This is how moderator staff gets painted as partisan, because they are

First, I suggest you stop calling us "staff" until we are paid to do the job. (And if you are expecting us to have much faster response times, you are going to need to pay us very well to leave our day jobs.)

Secondly, in my (probably unreliable) recollection, the main source of the mods being painted as partisan over the past few years has come from *you*, especially when you get thwarted from unfettered use of the site as a political platform. So, to me, this statement reads "This is how moderator staff gets painted as partisan: I keep painting you as partisan." I don't think it is making the cutting point you hoped.

Comment: I had no idea you didn't get paid.  I will henceforth lower my expectations to the "free hugs festival guy" level

Comment: Anyone care to unpack that comment for me? It has the cadence of an insult, but it is lacking any punch, so I assume it is like "soy-boy" where you need to be well acquainted with the accuser's ideology and false beliefs before you can even understand why it might be seen as a bad thing.